# Remove Multiple TABS in between data

Tags: linux, text-processing, whitespace

I have a tab delimited file, but in a few records, I see multiple TABS in between data

Sample Data: M^I^I^I^IJaghoub (^I is tab delimiter in cat -vet output) 
 Required Output: MJaghoub

I have used sed and tr command but was not successful.

Please advise how to remove multiple TABS only.

Comment: Do you only want to remove all instances of multiple tabs and leave the instances of single tabs alone?

Comment: @NasirRiley --you are correct, yes I need to  remove all instances of multiple tabs and leave the instances of single tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's|[\t][\t][\t]*||g' file.txt
```

That will remove any instance of two or more tabs but will not affect any instances of single tabs.

If you've confirmed that you have the desired output and you want to edit the file in place, you can add `-i`'

```
sed -i 's|[\t][\t][\t]*||g' file.txt
```

I've tested this with a file that has instances of 1,2,3,4 and 5 tabs it removed instances of multiple tabs while leaving instances of single tabs alone. It effectively removes any instance of two tabs with 0 or more tabs coming afterwards.

To confirm, I added some more lines with instances of multiple tabs and single tabs to what you have in your question:

The file with `cat -vet` (Don't worry about the `$`, it just represents a line ending. If you use `cat -vT`, it doesn't have the `$` for the line ending:

```
M^I^I^I^I^IJaghoub$
askdjfkasdf^I^Iksajk^I^Ijklsajkd$
klasjdfj^I^I^Ikljkasjdf^Ijaljkdsf$
asdkfj^I^I^Iklkljasdf^I^Ilkjkasdf$
sadfjkl^Ikjljas^Ikkjk^Ilkjlkj$
```

The output:

```
MJaghoub$
askdjfkasdfksajkjklsajkd$
klasjdfjkljkasjdf^Ijaljkdsf$
asdkfjklkljasdfkjkasdf$
sadfjkl^Ikjljas^Ikkjk^Ilkjlkj$
```

As you can see, it only removed instances of multiple tabs. The single tabs are still there.

Answer (score 2):

```
tr -s '\t' <file >newfile
```

should squeeze multiple tab characters occurring next to each other into single tabs in `file` and write the modified contents to `newfile`.

Change `-s` to `-d` to delete all tabs.